# Count Items by a Property Looked Up for each Item

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with a list of tasks in it. Each task can have blockers, which are other tasks in the same list, which must be completed before another can proceed. I have mocked up the table below:

[image: Example data mockup]

So in the example, the `Blocker1, Blocker2...` etc columns all have data validation to only allow values taken from the `Task` column. The `Done?` column can contain "Yes" or "No". The `BlockCount` column is meant to count the non-Done Tasks that block each task - that's where the problem is.

I would like to count how many of the blockers have been completed for each task by looking up the value in the `Done` column for each task that is listed as a blocker.

My best effort so far is this formula:

```
{=SUM(IF(INDEX([Done?],MATCH(Task[@[Blockers1]:[Blockers5]],[Title],0))="No",1,0))}
```

I confirmed the formula with `Ctrl+Enter`, trying to get the Index to work for each of the blockers, but this does not work. If I only take the `MATCH()` part of the formula, I successfully evaluate a range (shown below), but when I try to use that range to index different rows in the `Done?` column, it seems to only evaluate once, so I am confused what to do.

[image: Demo of Match evaluating range]

Can you help with a formula that will count the blockers in this way? I'm trying to list everything I need to do to fix up my house, and frankly this has started to become an time-consuming obsession that I so far have no prospect of solving!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(([Done]="No")*MMULT(--([Task]=Table2[@[Block1]:[Block5]]),ROW($A$1:$A$5)^0))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you and a Google for me about `MMULT`, of which I had never before heard.

Comment: 1) With Excel tables, it's preferable to avoid a mixture of structured table and standard referencing in formulas. So `ROW($A$1:$A$5)` should be replaced with the equivalent structured reference version. 2) More importantly, it should be made clear how the choice of range referenced within this `ROW` construction would need to be amended should the number of Blocker columns change. If we add a Blocker6 column, for example, your current set-up fails. Ideally, the range passed to `ROW` should be dynamically dependent on the number of Blocker columns, and not something static and unrelated .

Comment: That's a good point - I will replace with a dynamic named range that finds the blocker columns.

Answer (score 2):

You could approach this with COUNTIF:

`=SUM(COUNTIF(Table1[@[blocker1]:[blocker5]],[task])*([done?]="no"))`

If the current row `[blocker1:blocker5]` mention a task that appears in `[task]` it returns `1`(TRUE), else `0` (FALSE) for each value in the range (array).

Multiplying this array against the array of `1`'s and `0`'s returns (`1*1=`) `1` for each row where the task is found and `[done?]` says `no`. All others return `1*0`, `0*1`, or `0*0` all resulting in `0`.

SUM adds up the instances of blocker tasks found that mention `no`.

Older Excel versions need this formula entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`
[image]